# Is there a name for complex numbers over affinely extended reals?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, number-systems

Is there a name for the set of complex numbers over affinely extended real line, that is $\mathbb{C}\cup \{-\infty\}\cup\{+\infty\}$? I think this set is the most commonly used in analysis applications because the both extensions (complex numbers and affine reals) proved to be hugely fruitful in analysis.

For instance, this is a formula for inverse Mellin's transform from Wikipedia:
$$\left\{\mathcal{M}^{-1}\varphi\right\}(x) = f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} x^{-s} \varphi(s)\, ds$$

But I never encountered a name for this widely used numerical system.

Comment: Is it *widely used*? I have never seen it used at all, in fact.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez Look for instance at the Wiki article about Forier transform. It uses both complex numbers and signed infinities a lot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez And inverse Mellin tranform uses the both in one formula: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/4/a/54aca715828a45c0f8e1c3514fe26dcf.png

Comment: That notation has nothing to to with extended anything, really.

Comment: Note that your example is more like viewing $\mathbf{C} \subseteq \bar{\mathbf{R}} \times \bar{\mathbf{R}}$ rather than adding two extra points to the complex numbers. (where $\bar{\mathbf{R}}$ is the extended real numbers)

Comment: @Hurkyl  agreed, but what's the usual name (or symbol) for such set?